# How To Get Value From URL with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm making a download page by protecting the software download link from getting hotlinks. I want to make the URL expire if it has passed the specified time limit.

The code that I use requires a value from the URL. I have played around with this code but sadly my coding skills are not that good so I couldn't figure out how to modify it. I would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

**localhost/example/index.php**:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$salt = 'change me cause im not secure';
$path = '/download/tempfile.zip';
$timestamp = time() + 3600; // one hour valid
$hash = md5($salt . $ip . $timestamp . $path); // order isn't important at all... just do the same when verifying
$url = "http://localhost/example{$path}?s={$hash}&t={$timestamp}"; // use this as DL url
?>

<form action="download.php" method="get">
        <input name="bode" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $url; ?>">
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**localhost/example/download.php**:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$salt = 'change me cause im not secure';
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$hashGiven = $_GET['s'];
$timestamp = $_GET['t'];
$hash = md5($salt . $ip . $timestamp . $path);
if($hashGiven == $hash && $timestamp <= time()) {
    // serve file
} else {
    die('link expired or invalid');
} 
?>
```

**localhost/example/download.php?bode=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fexample%2Fdownload%2Ftempfile.zip%3Fs%3D86bc6c7959db1b3b2876a5d447c2528a%26t%3D1592559029**

page generated an error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: s in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\download.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: t in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\download.php on line 8
link expired or invalid
```

What's the solution?

Comment: You don't pass variables called `s` and `t` into your `download.php`, only a form variable called `bode`. The values you need are part of the string you pass in `bode`, not the URL.

Comment: This is not the complete code. I suspect you have somewhere something like `$url = http://localhost/example{urlencode($url)}`

Comment: @droopsnoot i insert in here `$url = "http://localhost/example{$path}?s={$hash}&t={$timestamp}"; // use this as DL url`

Comment: @Cid I wrote all the code. There is no such code.

Comment: Do you use a .htaccess file, that rewrites the urls?

Comment: @Marcel I do not have an htaccess file.I have not found a solution, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just check, if the url has the expected get parameters with the isset function.

```
$hashGiven = isset($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : '';
$timestamp = isset($_GET['t']) ? $_GET['t'] : '';
```

Do not trust parameters from an url. Always check and validate these parameters.

By the way ... your url looks encoded. This way single parameters will not be processed.

Comment: This can't yet be answered, some parts of the code that causes the issue are missing

Comment: Well, someway the given url is encoded. But this is not the point. The expected get paramters are not there and the given php code is not checking for this particular case. Even if the url is not encoded and does not contain the expected parameters it would throw a notice. It is absolutely necessary to check whether the parameters are present.

Comment: The fact the url is encoded **is** the point. if you decode that part `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fexample%2Fdownload%2Ftempfile.zip%3Fs%3D86bc6c7959db1b3b2876a5d447c2528a%26t%3D1592559029`, you get `http://localhost/example/download/tempfile.zip?s=86bc6c7959db1b3b2876a5d447c2528a&t=1592559029` which is the expected url

Comment: Yes, you 're right. In a perfect world the url contains always all expected parameters. But that is not the solution for the notices, that were thrown. What do you expect, if someone is manipulating the url and just deletes the `s` and `t` parameter? The php code will throw a notice because of not checking, if these parameters are set.

Comment: Of course, and I agree with you that inputs should be checked. However, this doesn't answer the question. This should be a comment or a part of the answer. Again, this question is impossible to answer yet (and then shouldn't be answered, yet), there are missing parts.

Answer (score 0):

The form action "download.php" needs to have the URL parameters 's' and 't' on it since that's what you're trying to get in the download file.

When the form submits as is, it's sending the URL input value, but that isn't the field you're checking for with $_GET fields in download.php.

Comment: I have tried entering the parameters "s" and "t", it managed to eliminate the error. However, on the download.php page the message **link expired or invalid** always appears, it looks like the hash parameter is not the same.

Comment: It's hard to debug that portion of the code without seeing the values of variables in download.php. Echo the GET vars, both hashes, both timestamps, and IP in that file to see what the values are and what doesn't match what you're expecting to see there.